# The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I try to create a trigger which can update a table named "Sala", but in "inserted.sala_cod", "sala.sala_cod" and "deleted.sala_cod" is marking The multi-part identifier "" could not be bound. Any solution?

```
Create Trigger ModificarSala
on Sala
for update
as
begin
update plantilla
set sala_cod = inserted.sala_cod
from plantilla
where sala.sala_cod = deleted.sala_cod
select * from inserted
end
```

Comment: Is that all of the SQL you are running? I can't see that the above would generate that specific error. Especially as you don't reference an object `''`.

Comment: You need to join the `inserted` table onto plantilla table somehow. And you can probably ignore the `deleted` table since you only want the value from `inserted`. Unsure why you are also trying to access the `sala` table since you already have that info in the `inserted` table.

Comment: The error appears in the three things I mentioned before, as " The multi-part identifier "inserted.sala_cod" could not be bound " is equal for the others too. And yes that's all the SQL

Comment: This code doesn't make sense - you are referring to the inserted and deleted tables, but not joining them. Also, a `for` trigger is an `after` trigger, so when you write `where sala.sala_cod = deleted.sala_cod` it means where the `sala_cod` column did not change it's value. And the `select * from inserted` is probably useless as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to the inserted and deleted

```
Create Trigger ModificarSala
on Sala
for update
as
begin
update p
set sala_cod = inserted.sala_cod
from plantilla p
join inserted on inserted.? = p.? 
join deleted inserted.? = deleted.?
--join sala on sala.sala_cod = deleted.sala_cod --maybe this is needed? We need your DDL
end
```